# Destruir um conteiner já criado no tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para destruir um contêiner já apresentado na tela. Tipo assim: o programa carrega um contêiner com os *widgets* e tudo. No entanto, quando faço ele criar outro contêiner, ele coloca em baixo do já criado. Eu queria que ele destruísse o primeiro e depois criasse o segundo. Tem como?

Comment: Já tentou usar método _destroy_ do objeto? ex: `container_a_ser_destruido.destroy()`